# Issues with arrays that says undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a little project with some quotes and I want to output them on a div and the console keeps throwing me "cannot read property "null" of undefined" and I don't know why or where is the error.

My current code is this:

```
var daHash = location.hash.substring(1),
    wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
    favs = localStorage.getItem("quoteLoved"),
    favA = favs.split(","),
    modal = document.getElementById("modal"),
    overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

modal.style.display = "block";
overlay.style.display = "block";
for (var i = 0; i < (favA.length - 1); i++) {
    var favQ = favA[i];
    modal.innerHTML = modal.innerHTML + "<section>" + "<cite class=' id " + favQ + "' contenteditable='true'>arroz" + "</cite>" + "<p class= id " + favQ + ">queso" + "<span class='dev_fav'></span>" + "</p>" + "</section>";
};
for (var i = 0; i < (favA.length - 1); i++) {
    var classes = Number(modal.getElementsByClassName("id")[i].classList.item(2));
    modal.getElementsByClassName("id")[i].innerHTML = quotes[classes];
};
location.hash = "";
```

The problem that Chrome throws is on `modal.getElementsByClassName("id")[i].innerHTML = quotes[classes];`

`quotes[classes]` is an array with various texts inside.

EDIT:

The quotes array is something like this:

```
var quotes = [
    "Some text blah",
    "Some text blah blah",
    "Some text blah blah and blah blah, you know.."
];
```

When I do all this on console no error is thrown and I don't know why it throws when it executes the script.

Comment: Step 1: figure out what's `undefined`. Should be easy enough to get started debugging.

Comment: Where is that `quotes` defined? Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: that is the problem mate, I don't know why it says ´undefined´ when it works with all the other functions of the script. @DaveNewton

Comment: sorry mate, but I can't(secret quote). But I will modify the post with a random array : ) @bebraw

Comment: Throw some `console.log()` in there? Because it really looks like `quotes` is undefined, and `classes` is null. Try and work your way backwards and figure out how those variables get populated.

Also, are you using `id` as a class name? That's just ... confusing.

Comment: So start debugging. That's what most of programming is; put in breakpoints. Console logging. Heck, even alerts. Find out what's undefined.

Comment: Best way to find the problem at this point would be if you could create a jsfiddle.net with a smaller version of your code and share it here.

Comment: You have to check if "classes" is returning with a value to properly indexing "quotes"

Comment: @RaphaelSerota I put a class as ´ID´ because ´favQ´ is the ´ID´ of the quote.

Comment: @ADASein I've already done that and it returns 2 things: id and the number of favQ

Comment: @DaveNewton already done that and keeps throwing that error

Comment: You are not listening: quotes[classes] is reaching a non existence index. Thus, classes isn't always returning a value that is an index of quotes.

Comment: I could be wrong, but to check if I am, harcode classes, instead of quotes[classes] use quotes[0] or whatever real index you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64428/discussion-between-mr-swaggalicious-and-adasein).

Comment: Problem 1: `quotes` is undefined when you refer to it in the code above. You must be running this function at a point in the programme's flow where `quotes` has not yet been defined, or else has been somehow reset, or defining `quotes` inside another function that is outside the scope of this function. It's impossible to say why without seeing more context. Problem 2: `classes` is also null, which is a result of the content of the element "modal". We can't tell why without seeing what that element contains.

Comment: yeah, my bad. @Stuart. Quotes is always defined because is on another file. I found that classes was returning null because it was not a number and now I converted it to a number with Number().

Comment: Don't edit your title with "SOLVED". If you've fixed the problem, add an answer and, in a couple of days, you'll be able to accept it.

Comment: So, the debugging idea ("identify what's `undefined`") was probably a good one. Checking your assumptions, not just at the "but the console showed xyz" level, is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem, `quotes` variable name was already used by a non array variable, renamed the other variable and the code is now working. Thanks for the help. With a bit of debugging and carefully reading through the script code I finally found the error.